# LinkedIn Ad Analytics API - Ad Metrics Are Low When Using Pivots

Tags: api, analytics, linkedin-api, reporting, ads

We are working on integrating with the LinkedIn Ad Analytics API and have basic Ad-level data coming in correctly and reconciling against the LinkedIn UI. The problem is that when we try to add pivots such as MEMBER_REGION, the totals do not match and all metrics are lower than they should be, and to varying degrees. We have verified that pagination isn't an issue, as we appear to be getting all records back, and the totals are still off even if we manually go through all of the returned JSON and add up the metrics.

This is the call that we are using (this one for a specific Ad ID of 70571643)  :

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?dateRange.start.year=2018&dateRange.start.month=08&dateRange.start.day=02&dateRange.end.year=2018&dateRange.end.month=08&dateRange.end.day=02&q=analytics&timeGranularity=DAILY&creatives[0]=urn:li:sponsoredCreative:70571643&pivot=MEMBER_REGION

For the example, we should be seeing 855 total Impressions and 24.00 total CostInLocalCurrency, but we are getting back records which total 821 Impressions and 0.00 CostInLocalCurrency.

Any help or insight as to why we are seeing these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

so the difference you see is because of the visablity of an account. Linkedin has an option to protect yourself from surtain publicity and the API is a factor in this. so 34 people have protected account. ( this also applies to a total of likes on a update, etc. )

the costinlocalcurrency i cannot explain. maybe the cost factors of those users as well but i cannot be certain of that.

Comment: While I would expect some minor variation in the metrics, like what we are seeing in impressions, the total cost being $0 still doesn't make sense, so I'm pretty sure that there's another issue. Also, if that were the case, then the impressions should be consistently off across all of the other pivots like COMPANY, COMPANY_SIZE, JOB_TITLE, etc... and that's not the case, and in fact some are showing even higher totals for impressions.